# How can I use the sufficient statistics (variances, covariances, means) to estimate a linear regression model in R?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

My question is simple: is there a function in `R` which estimates the linear regresion model in a similar fashion as `lm`, but only using the means, variances, and covariance (correlations), i.e. the sufficient statistics? I am looking for a function to which I can input these statistics (plus sample size) and it returns regression coefficients and tests.

Comment: The estimates are found as described at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107597/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-covariance-matrix-to-find-coefficients-for-multiple-re.  With these in hand, any test you want is obtained in a standard fashion.

Comment: Thanks -- supose sample size n varies over cells of the variance-covariance matrix (for example due to item nonresponse and more particular due to the problem described in this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110559/estimate-linear-regression-using-items-randomly-selected-from-an-item-pool?noredirect=1#comment212379_110559). Should the relevant tests be adapted somehow?

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer--but is best addressed at the other thread you started.

Comment: I figure that in this situation multiple imputation might be another approach to deal with the problem (see my comment on the other thread).